# Building production folder with Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I'm using Gulp on a project and noticed two problems:

1. Images are not being copied to the `dist` folder. I'm using `imagemin` to do this but the Images folder simply is not build. I checked multiple times the root of the folder, but I can't seem to find the mistake. Here is my folder organization:

`|- app/
      |- css/
      |- fonts/
      |- images/ 
      |- index.html
      |- js/ 
           |- jQuery Nice Select/
           |- jQuery Validation/
      |- scss/
|- dist/
|- gulpfile.js
|- node_modules/
|- package.json`

2. I'm using the *jQuery Validate* Plugin and the *NiceSelect* Plugin. They seem not to be included on the *build task*. Up on production, validation doesn't work, neither the select, because it looks like the one rendered by Chrome.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<!--build:js js/main.min.js -->
<script src="js/simulador.js"></script>         
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script src="js/lib/jquery-validation-1.16.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-nice-select/jquery.nice-select.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
        },
    })
});

gulp.task('useref', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
    return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); 
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean:dist', 
      ['sass', 'useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
      callback
    )
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are intending gulp-cache and not gulp-cached (or similar gulp-changed).  They are quite different.  If you only want to minimize images that are new try gulp-cached or gulp-changed.

Comment: The thing is that I don't even get the Images folder on dist/, so it's not about new images, it's about all of them. Thanks!

Comment: So try gulp-changed for example instead of gulp-cached.